# Using OpenCV, how to draw contours INSIDE the edges of detected shape/blob?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android

Following is an image of a blue colored blob detected in an Android app using `OpenCV4Android`. I used [`Core.inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) and [`Imgproc.findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) methods to find the contours, and [`Imgproc.drawContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours) to draw them:

```
Mat mask = new Mat();
Core.inRange(rgbaMat, lowerThreshold, upperThreshold, mask);
...
contours = new ArrayList<>();
Imgproc.findContours(dilatedMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
...
for ( int contourIdx=0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++ ) { 
    Imgproc.drawContours ( rgbaMat, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
}
```

The contour (light green boundary) is outside the detected shape.

So, as you can see, it also includes some white area around the detected blue blob. I want the contour boundary to be inside the edges of the blue blob/shape.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in your code that you applied "findContours" on variable "dilatedMat" (line #5). I assume that you applied "dilate" filter on "rgbaMat" (somewhere on line #3). But if you want the contours be inside, you should apply **"erode" instead of "dilate"**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some negative value in drawContour thickness parameter, that will draw the contour inside the detected object.

```
Imgproc.drawContours ( rgbaMat, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1);
```